# _USE_32BIT_TIME_T equivalent for gcc

Tags: gcc, time-t

On Visual studio I can force use of 32-bit `time_t` by declaring `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T`. Is there a similar equivalent for gcc? or is it always 32-bit or is it always 64-bit?

Comment: 32-bit `time_t` is a bad idea. 64-bit `time_t` should be used instead, even in 32-bit Linux: [Is there any way to get 64-bit `time_t` in 32-bit programs in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14361651/995714)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `time_t` type is not defined by gcc but rather by system library. On Linux, this is glibc, and it defines `time_t` in `time.h` header:

```
typedef __time_t time_t;
```

which is in turn defined in `bits/types.h`:

```
__STD_TYPE __TIME_T_TYPE __time_t;
```

(`__STD_TYPE` definition is not interesting),

`__TIME_T_TYPE` is defined in `bits/typesizes.h`:

```
#define __TIME_T_TYPE __SLONGWORD_TYPE
```

which is in turn defined in `bits/types.h`:

```
#define __SLONGWORD_TYPE long int
```

which is 32 bits on 32 bits system, 64 bits on 64 bits system. All these definitions are unconditional, so, no `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T` equivalent on glibc.

Comment: so as long as I compiled on 32 bit platform it should be fine. any info for gcc on Mac?

Comment: @SnapConfig.com You can check Mac headers the same way I did on Linux