# Is there any way to get 64-bit time_t in 32-bit programs in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, 64-bit, time-t

On Windows I can call:

```
_time32(__time32_t); // to get 32-bit time_t
_time64(__time64_t); // to get 64-bit time_t
```

(both in 32 and 64-bit programs)

Is there any way do this in Linux (compiling with GCC)?

Comment: @Benoit That question is not a duplicate, it's completely different.

Comment: Not really...on 32-bit Linux, `time_t` is a traditional 32-bit signed quantity, with only 25 years of useful life left in it.  On 64-bit Unix systems, it is already a 64-bit quantity.  If you want a portable type, you'll have to define your own that maps appropriately, or just use `time_t` carefully.  The other question referenced has relevant information (but I agree it is not a duplicate).

Comment: see also **[64-bit UNIX Timestamp Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914368/64-bit-unix-timestamp-conversion)**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently, no it's not possible. For starters, there is only one `time()` function in Linux, no `time32()` or `time64()`.

After searching for a while, I can see that it's not libc's fault, but the culprit is actually the kernel.

In order for libc to fetch the current time, it need to execute a system call for it: <sup>([Source](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/time.c;h=d447d3caa1eb6d47727ea6cc5cc73e5edbec43ba;hb=HEAD#l30))</sup>

```
time_t time (t) time_t *t;
{
    // ...
    INTERNAL_SYSCALL_DECL (err);
    time_t res = INTERNAL_SYSCALL (time, err, 1, NULL);
    // ...
    return res;
}
```

The system call is defined as: <sup>([Source](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=kernel/time.c;h=d226c6a3fd28933d02edd485a9c8353db2212c02;hb=406089d01562f1e2bf9f089fd7637009ebaad589#l62))</sup>

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(time, time_t __user *, tloc)
{
    time_t i = get_seconds();
    // ...
    return i;
}
```

The function `get_seconds()` returns an `unsigned long`, like so: <sup>([Source](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=kernel/time/timekeeping.c;h=cbc6acb0db3fafbaa4830da34cdb22e538892764;hb=406089d01562f1e2bf9f089fd7637009ebaad589#l1296))</sup>

```
unsigned long get_seconds(void)
{
    struct timekeeper *tk = &timekeeper;

    return tk->xtime_sec;
}
```

And `timekeeper.xtime_sec` is actually 64-bit: <sup>([Source](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=include/linux/timekeeper_internal.h;h=e1d558e237ecfdd8059106c4e98f488ff406ff12;hb=406089d01562f1e2bf9f089fd7637009ebaad589#l30))</sup>

```
struct timekeeper {
    // ...
    /* Current CLOCK_REALTIME time in seconds */
    u64                     xtime_sec;
    // ...
}
```

Now, if you know your C, you know that the size of `unsigned long` is actually implementation-dependant. On my 64-bit machine here, it's 64-bit; but on my 32-bit machine here, it's 32-bit. It *possibly* could be 64-bit on some 32-bit implementation, but there's no guarantee.

On the other hand, `u64` is always 64-bit, so at the very base, the kernel keeps track of the time in a 64-bit type. Why it then proceeds to return this as an `unsigned long`, which is not guaranteed to be 64-bit long, is beyond me.

In the end, even if libc's would force `time_t` to hold a 64-bit value, it wouldn't change a thing.

You could tie your application deeply into the kernel, but I don't think it's even worth it.

Comment: So, write a patch and post it. Both for libc (typedef long long int time_t) and the kernel long long int get_seconds(void)

Comment: @user877329 changing the type of existing functions breaks many things, so new syscalls had to be introduced for 64-bit time instead. See below

Answer (score 18):

Many answers above said that this is impossible, but that's **entirely incorrect**. It *was* not possible at that time yet people had been [talking about fixing it](https://lwn.net/Articles/599580/) for years. Finally 64-bit time support on 32-bit platforms was [introduced to the Linux 5.1 kernel](https://lwn.net/Articles/776427/) with the addition of the new [`*time64` syscalls](https://lwn.net/ml/linux-kernel/20190110172216.313063-12-arnd@arndb.de/). Look at [this table](https://fedora.juszkiewicz.com.pl/syscalls.html) you can see that those syscalls are only available on 32-bit platforms. Now if you're writing code for 32-bit systems you can call `clock_gettime64` directly (from inline assembly or C with [`syscall()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html)) to get the current time

However after that you're completely on your own. If you want full *userspace* support you must be on Linux 5.6 or higher along with musl 1.2+ or glibc 2.32+. Just rebuild your code and your `time_t` will become 64-bit long

> - All user space must be compiled with a 64-bit `time_t`, which will be supported in the coming musl-1.2 and glibc-2.32 releases, along with installed kernel headers from linux-5.6 or higher.
> - Applications that use the system call interfaces directly need to be ported to use the `time64` syscalls added in linux-5.1 in place of the existing system calls. This impacts most users of `futex()` and `seccomp()` as well as programming languages that have their own runtime environment not based on libc.
>
> https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/1/29/355?anz=web

For more information

- [Approaching the kernel year-2038 end game](https://lwn.net/Articles/776435/)
- [64-bit time symbol handling in the GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/64_002dbit-time-symbol-handling.html)
- [glibc Y2038 Proofness Design](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Y2038ProofnessDesign)
- [Change time_t and clock_t to 64 bit](https://lwn.net/Articles/598408/)

Comment: On my 32 bit Linux 5.4 i can't call `clock_gettime64` etc. It tells me undefined reference. What do I need to include/define/install in order for it to work?

Comment: @arminb how do you call it? It's a system call, not a C function. In C you'll need to use `syscall()` as I mentioned above, but you need to know how to put the syscall number and how to put all the register values

Comment: Yes, I know, I call it like this: `syscall(SYS_clock_gettime64, ...);`. It says "error: 'SYS_clock_gettime64' undeclared ... did you mean 'SYS_clock_gettime"

Comment: @arminb you can see how it's called in [musl](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/time/clock_gettime.c#n75). See also [this](https://github.com/richfelker/musl-cross-make/issues/96). If that doesn't help then please ask that in another question

Comment: @phuclv is it possible to compile a 32 bit ARM architecture with 64 bit `time_t`?

Comment: @D.Smith yes, of course. If you have the appropriate versions of kernel and libc then just compile the code and `time_t` will automatically be 64-bit as I said. If you have the correct kernel but not libc then do the syscall manually: `syscall(403, CLOCK_REALTIME, custom_timespec_struct);` with 403 being the [syscall number for clock_gettime64](https://marcin.juszkiewicz.com.pl/download/tables/syscalls.html) in ARM

Comment: @phuclv I have compiled a custom Linux 5.10 with custom gcc toolchain using glibc 2.32 and `sizeof(time_t)` still returns 4, `__TIMESIZE` is still set to 32. I'm not sure how to achieve 64 bit `time_t`.

Comment: @D.Smith I think there are some issues with your custom gcc. Please ask a separate question on that

Comment: @phuclv I have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884032/glibc-set-timesize

Comment: Just popped in to add: on musl, and I believe in glibc, it's not necessary to have a kernel with time64 support in order to use 64-bit time_t. On an older kernel, you'll be limited not to set the current time or file timestamps past Y2038, but you can still use the new ABI for applications and they'll be all ready to go when you move to a newer kernel.

Comment: Apparently you actually need glibc 2.34+ (not 2.32+).  Also, you *must* enable LFS (large file support) or the compilation will fail.  This is annoying because you can't just force _TIME_BITS=64 regardless of architecture, you need to actually detect you're on 32-bits and THEN force-enable _TIME_BITS=64, and the LFS defines, otherwise you get compilation errors...

Comment: Interestingly, even with glibc 2.36 (Debian Bookworm on armhf), it does not automatically use 64-bit `time_t` for me. Instead, I have to manually specify it in CFLAGS in order to use 64bit instead of 32bit `time_t` (e.g. `DEB_CXXFLAGS_APPEND="-D_TIME_BITS=64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64"` before `debuild` if compiling Debian package), otherwise it continues to use 32-bit `time_t`

Answer (score 7):

No `time64()/time32()` function are included into standard libraries.

No `time32_t/time64_t` defines are contemplated in standard headers.

`time_t` is defined into `time.h` as `typedef __time_t time_t`;

Following a long chain of redefines, you'll discover that `__time_t` is defined as 32 bit on 32 bit machines and 64bit on 64 bit machines.

Answer (score 1):

Use this library: https://github.com/evalEmpire/y2038

> The goal of this project is to provide a drop-in replacement for POSIX
>   time.h which will work on machines which have a 32-bit time_t, yet not
>   suffer from the 2038 bug. This will allow C programmers to be
>   2038-safe without having to rewrite their software to a new interface.
>   It does this while still using the system time zone database.

Answer (score -4):

If you really need this, why not roll your own?

```
typedef int32_t my_time32;
typedef int64_t my_time64;


my_time32 get_mytime32() {
    if (sizeof(time_t) == sizeof(my_time32))
        return time(NULL);
    else {
        /* Check for overflow etc. here... */
        return (my_time32)(time(NULL));
    }
}
```

And similarly for `get_mytime64()`.

If you do not care about overflow, a simple `return time(NULL);` would work for both functions thanks to C's implicit numeric conversions.

Comment: I don't think a simple return time(NULL); would work for get_mytime64() on 32-bit platforms - it would just truncate.

Comment: @rsaxvc Yes hence the "check for overflow etc here" comment. In general you have a problem dealing with 32-bit times